# how to use api key parameter to post json data with manual api key using curl

Tags: php, mysql, api, curl

How do  I insert json post data with curl and api key parameter.

In the following code I'm trying to add an `apikey` parameter in the url.

```
index.php:

$data = array(
    // 'name' => '100236',
 //    'age' => '265',
    'nric' => '123546',
    'id' => '266',
    'fullname'=>'sairam',
    'gender' => 'M',
    'password' => '123546',
    'address'=>'jlnklmanalpoi',
    'postcode' => '502103',
    'state' => 'telangana',
    'contact1'=>'+60123654',
     'email' => 'email@email.com',
    'rank'=>'AM',
   'expirydate'=>'14-07-2017'

);
  $post_json = json_encode($data);

          $api_key = '99999your9999api999keyd4eae7c3';    
       $endpoint = 'http://localhost/apib/data.php?key=.$api_key ';
        $ch = @curl_init();
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_json);
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = @curl_exec($ch);
        $status_code = @curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $curl_errors = curl_error($ch);
        @curl_close($ch);
        echo "curl Errors: " . $curl_errors;
        echo "\nStatus code: " . $status_code;
        echo "\nResponse: " . $response;
?>

am unable to use api key below page :
```

this is end point data.php

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);


if (isset($_POST['nric'],$_POST['id'],$_POST['fullname'],$_POST['gender'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['address'],$_POST['postcode'],$_POST['state'],$_POST['contact1'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['rank'],$_POST['expirydate'])) {

 global $db;
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ilde");
if($db === false)
{

    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

    $nric=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["nric"]);
    $id =(int)$_POST["id"];
     $fullname=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["fullname"]);
      $gender=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["gender"]);
```

i want to use secure url with apikey manually.please help me to solve this.    how to insert json post data with curl and api key parameter.please help me below is my code i am trying to add apikey parameter in url

Comment: change `$endpoint = 'http://localhost/apib/data.php?key=.$api_key ';` to `$endpoint = 'http://localhost/apib/data.php?key='.$api_key;`

Comment: okay .but in data.php file how can i write api_key is matching or not?

Comment: You can retrieve key by `$_GET['key'];` in data.php

Comment: $api_key = '99999your9999api999keyd4eae7c3';   this is an api key data.php given to index.php using this key index.php need to push data to data.php. so now we need to  $api_key = '99999your9999api999keyd4eae7c3';   in data.php??

Comment: I already mentioned you can get it by **`$api_key = $_GET['key']`** in **data.php**

Comment: only this  is $api_key = $_GET['key']  enough in data.php??

Comment: how can we now is thar exact api key or not?

Comment: Really unclear what you are trying to ask here ... _“how can we now is thar exact api key or not?”_ - what do you mean? Are you asking about how a 3rd-party API will react to the key not being valid, or are you asking how to handle this in your own API you are trying to create here? (And if the latter, I would have to say straight away, please go learn some basics before you try to implement something like this yourself; the initial "string issue" rather suggests these are not really present at the moment.)

Comment: i want to create manually an api key using that key and using curl  index.php will push some data to data.php .my question is that api key should me unique .soo how can i do it as unique if i enter different key that data should not be inerted to data.php

Answer (score -1):

Try below endpoint:

```
$endpoint = 'http://localhost/apib/data.php?key='.$api_key.' ';
```

Comment: okay .but i just assigned api key manually in index.php and it should match with in data.php also .but can i write in data.php .even if i enter  different key it is aslo working but i need unique api key .please help me